# How to set landscape media queries for tab and mobile in css?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, tablet, landscape

I am creating an android app using web view.My app always open in landscape mode.I need different UI for mobile and tab(both in landscape mode).How to set landscape media queries for tab and mobile  in css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a media query to set to landscape, you need to use the property `orientation` like this :

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

To aim only mobile, tabs, computer screens, you need to use the rule `screen`. So the final result is something like this :

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Comment: Well i don't know for sure. There is a plenty of mobile widths. You have to test it on different configurations. Sorry...